# drag drop issue

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement an example of perform drag and drop in android studio 3.0.1. When I drag the image, it disappears. I am new to android and could not figure out what is going on. The example I am trying to follow is given on this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm

Here is my code of MainActivity:

```
package com.example.osman.dragdrop2;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ImageView img;
    String msg;
    private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        img.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(img);

                v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
                return true;
            }
        });

        img.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                        x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                        Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");

                        // Do nothing
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(img);

                    img.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, img, 0);
                    img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }



    }
```

Here is the code of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.osman.dragdrop2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Drag the below image"
        android:textColor="#ff14be3c"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/abc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to fix the problem. Here is the code of MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.osman.dragdrop2;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintTableLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ImageView img;
    String msg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.imageView).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

        findViewById(R.id.rel).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());



    }


    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }


    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);

                    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;

                    int    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int    y_cord = (int) event.getY();

                    view.setX(x_cord);
                    view.setY(y_cord);
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**And Here is the code of layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.osman.dragdrop2.MainActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/abc" />





</RelativeLayout>
```